# Docker: error waiting for container: copying response body from Docker: unexpected EOF During running container

Tags: docker, eof

I tried running docker container and it fails with this error

> error waiting for container: copying response body from Docker: unexpected EOF\n

i built image using this command:

```
docker-compose build cve
```

and ran it with

```
docker-compose run cve
```

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  cve:
    build: .
    env_file: .environment
```

and
here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

copy .. .
ENTRYPOINT ["python","./main.py"]
```

Im using docker desktop on windows.
I tried to reinstall docker but problrm persists.

Comment: Is it possible you're running of memory or storage space?  I found a [similar issue reported here](https://github.com/heneault/yocto-pitrezor/issues/12), which they resolved by assigning more resources.

Comment: Found another identical issue reported - due to Docker pipeline running out of memory, so that's the likely issue: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Building-React-docker-image-fail-by-unexpected-EOF/qaq-p/947346

Comment: If you `docker-compose run` a temporary container, you need to give an alternate command for it to run.  Do you mean `docker-compose up` to run the standard container setup?